# Dates of DateTime type not getting matched

Tags: c#, datetime

I am comparing two variables of DateTime type, say `d1` and `d2`, which are seemingly equal but the compare function returns `1` instead of `0`. The value as printed for both of them is `12/10/2015 9:44:52 AM`

`d1` is lastModified, DateTime property of a file which is saved as a string `s1` in a file.

```
String s1 = d1.ToUniversalTime().ToString();
```

When this file is later read for the string as

```
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse(s1) ;
```

The comparison between the two dates is weirdly not zero as expected, since they are equal, using the following

```
DateTime.Compare(d1.ToUniversalTime(),d2)
```

If I string compare both d1 and d2 after converting them to strings, they are equal and both print the above mentioned value.

I have been struggling to find out why when the date saved as string to a file and read again to be changed into date do not match.

Comment: Are you comparing `d1` and `d2`, or are you comparing `d1.ToUniversalTime()` and `d2`?

Comment: @SonerGönül : yes d1.toutc() and d2 when printed are seen as the same time 12/10/2015 9:44:52 AM also when changed to strings and compared are exactly same. Will have to Check CurrentCulture but looks like it is en-us as it's of mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: @hvd : since d2 is got from a string converted to utc time , I am comparing d1 converted to utc.

Comment: That's good. Please make sure to specify that in your question though: your question says in multiple places you're comparing `d1` and `d2`, and it makes perfect sense for those not to compare as equal.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it. Let's look at line by line.

```
String s1 = d1.ToUniversalTime().ToString();
```

With that line, you are generating `12/10/2015 9:44:52 AM` as string representation of your `d1.ToUniversalTime()` *without* any milliseconds part.

```
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse(s1) ;
```

With that line, you are parsing this string to DateTime `12/10/2015 9:44:52` as a value but it's millisecond part will be zero.

That's why your `d1.ToUniversalTime()` will *always* bigger than `dt2` and it is *too* normal to return a value bigger than zero from `DateTime.Compare` method.

> If I string compare both d1 and d2 after converting them to strings,
>   they are equal and both print the above mentioned value.

I assume you use `ToString()` method to generate their string representations, this method uses [The `"G"` standard format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) for parameterless overload and this specifier does not represent milliseconds part for any culture as far as I know.

If you use some `f`, `ff`, `fff`... date and time specifiers in your `ToString()` method, I'm quite sure you see different results as their representations.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not sure if milli-seconds are involved because I do not see them when they are printed. Secondly, when I execute all these steps without saving the string to a file and then reading it back again the comparison returns 0.
It is only when the string is saved and read back again that I face the difference.

Comment: @Hodor Because `ToString()` uses The `"G"` format specifier and this specifier does not represent milliseconds part. If you use `ToString("fff")` for example, I'm quite sure you see the difference. If you compare them their values, it is too normal to return `0` since they are equal. But when you get it's string representation and parse it to `DateTime` again, since your string does not have milliseconds part, your `d2` will not have milliseconds part as well. That's why your `d1.ToUniversalTime()` will _always_ be bigger than `d2`. Generating and parsing it again generates different result.

Comment: Thanks Soner! I will try this :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [round trip format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Roundtrip) `"o"` to convert to your persistable string, else you loose the milliseconds.

```
String s1 = d1.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o");
```

Also, just to be safe, I would use the InvariantCulture to parse it (probably not necessary if your thread culture is always english).

```
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse(s1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4jTvb4)

-- EDIT-- Use `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` for parsing as recommended on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks Georg! Will try.